# c# - how to invert two dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, rows

I have a program which performs a long processing. The first step is converting table from XML format to 2 dimensional array (arr[,]). After that many steps are perfomed and only after them I know if the table has row title or column title. To make it clear, row title means table like:

```
Name    city   id
Anna     NY     1
Joe      NJ     2
```

column title means:

```
Name    Anna     Joe
City    NY       NJ
id      1        2
```

The table is processed according to the title. I take to values related to some title and work on them. I'm looking for a way to represent the table in one way so I shouldn't check each time if the table type is rows or columns. I want to avoid something like to following code:

```
List<Cell> cells;
if (tableType == rows)
  cells = table.getCol("Name");
else
  cells = table.getRow("Name")
```

I would be happy to any suggestion.

Thanks!

Comment: if you have an 2D array you'll have probably a nested for loop. Inverse the loops. Or clarify your question.

Comment: What have you tried? This should be some simple code with loops and a little index calculation.

Comment: What you need is called Pivoting.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687708/pivoting-a-collection-of-arrays

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you rotate a two dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519/how-do-you-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 0):

Have a method that's called instead of `table.getCol` and `table.getRow` and then calls them.

Something like:

```
static bool IsColumns = true;
List<Cell> Get(string input)
{
    if (IsColumns) return table.getCol(input);
    else return table.getRow(input);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There some nice code taken from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519/how-do-you-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array)

```
int[,] array = new int[4,4] {
    { 1,2,3,4 },
    { 5,6,7,8 },
    { 9,0,1,2 },
    { 3,4,5,6 }
};

int[,] rotated = RotateMatrix(array, 4);

static int[,] RotateMatrix(int[,] matrix, int n) {
    int[,] ret = new int[n, n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
             ret[i, j] = matrix[j, i];
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: OP wants transposition, as far as I can see, so `ret[i, j] = matrix[j, i];`.